# How to compare a list of routes with a dictionary of costs between arcs?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gurobi

Hello to the whole community,

I have a question about creating an automatic method (function or loop+) to declare a route cost variable, which involves the sum of each of the c_i,j arcs.

Example:

```py
routes=[[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0)],[(0, 1), (1, 0)],[(0, 2), (2, 0)]]  #  list of 3 possible routes in 2 locations where 0 is depot

cij = {(0,1): 3,(0, 2): 4,(0, 3): 5,(1, 0):3,(1, 2):5,(1, 3):7 ,(2, 0):4,(2, 1):5, (2, 3):9}  # dictionary with cost matrix between the arcs [i,j]
```

I would like to get help to reach a `RouteCost` variable that compares the list with the dictionary and will add each of the arcs it finds per route.
For example, there would be a list of costs for the 3 routes:

```py
RouteCost= [12,6,8]
```

Thank you for your help and keep up the good work to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be performed using a nested list comprehension:

```py
RouteCost = [sum([cij[path] for path in route]) for route in routes]
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Roy Bubis. It works perfectly. I need to learn more about nested list comprehension. I've been trying to replicate the question with for loop, but without sucess. Now with for loop it was very different? In terms of computing is the same?

Comment: List comprehensions are identical in terms of computation to a for loop - they are simply a more concise and "pythonic" way of achieving the same result. You can read about nested list comprehensions here: [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nested-list-comprehensions-in-python/).

Comment: Thanks again @Roy. I was reading this link and it helped me. I tried to return the same in a for loop taking into account the comprehencion list. But the result returns `RouteCost=[3,5,4,3,3,4,4]`, it basically calculates the price with each path in route and doesn't add up the total route. Did I do something wrong? Thanks for the support
`RouteCost=[]
for route in routes:
    for path in route:
        RouteCost+=[(sum([c[path]]))]`

Comment: If you use explicit for loops there's no need for list comprehension. You can use the following code: `RouteCosts = []
    for route in routes:
        cost = 0
        for path in route:
            cost += cij[path]
        RouteCosts.append(cost)`